# Change progress bar with circular wait image

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, gtk

Is it possible to skin the GTK+ progress bar widget such that it shows a custom image (an AJAX style animated gif maybe)? If so how and if not, is there any other option/control which can achieve this effect?

Comment: This is called a throbber (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throbber#Spinning_wheel).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like [GtkSpinner](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkSpinner.html)?